# Is relatively free the same thing as induced for finite group modules?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, finite-groups

I was looking over Alperin's Local Representation Theory and I realized I remembered a definition that may not be there (or true).

> Is a relatively *H*-free *G*-module exactly the same as a *G*-module isomorphic to an induced *H*-module?

Lemma 8.4 on [page 56](http://books.google.com/books?id=p7ylsZUmK3MC&pg=PA56) shows that induced modules are relatively *H*-free, and the other direction seems like some sort of restatement of Frobenius reciprocity, but since the book doesn't mention the equivalence, I worry it is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to remember that definition comes with the extra information of the $kH$-submodule with respect to which the module is relatively free. Proposition 8.2 says relatively H-free modules with respect to X exist and Lemma 8.1 says they are unique up to isomorphism. Lemma 8.4 says that the induced module $V^G$ is relatively $H$-free with respect to $V$ and by Lemma 8.1 it is the unique module with this property. Hence every relatively $H$-free $kG$-module is of the form $X^G$ for some $X$, and that $X$ is precisely the submodule with respect to which the module is relatively $H$-free.

Comment: Thanks!  This is very clear.  Now I don't doubt my memories as much.