# Mackey and relatively projective modules

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, finite-groups

While reading over Alperin's Local Representation Theory and reminding myself how a module is relatively *H*-projective iff *H* contains some vertex of the module, I realized I could not prove a basic lemma about relatively *H*-projective modules using my current favorite definition.

**Definition:** A *G*-module *U* is relatively *H*-projective if *U* is a direct summand of $(U_H)^G$.

**Lemma:** If *H* ≤ *K* ≤ *G* and *U* is a *G*-module that is relatively *H*-projective, then *U* is relatively *K*-projective.

**Proof:** Use Prop 9.1.2 to change definitions of relatively projective back to the good ole relative homological definition I used to like: *H*-split implies *G*-split.  Clearly *K*-split implies *H*-split just by restricting the direct sum, but then relatively *H*-projectivity (Prop 9.1.2 style) gives *G*-split, but this suffices to show relative *K*-projectivity (Prop 9.1.2 style).  $\square$

However, when I try to do this with $U|(U_H)^G$ I get confused and can't seem to use Mackey correctly.  In Alperin's proof on [page 67](http://books.google.com/books?id=p7ylsZUmK3MC&pg=PA67) he uses a similar but more convenient definition: that *U* is a direct summand of an induced *H*-module.  Assuming [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62739/is-relatively-free-the-same-thing-as-induced-for-finite-group-modules) is right, this is exactly the same as a direct summand of a relatively free module.  However, I'm not sure I see how $U|(U_H)^G$ is equivalent to $U|S^G$ for some *H*-module *S*.  Presumably this is Frobenius reciprocity, but again something is going wrong when I try to do it.  At any rate, with the "S" definition it is just transitivity of induction, so I'd like to understand both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing you need is that $S\uparrow^G $ is relatively $H$-projective in the following sense: for all surjections $M_1 \to M_2$ of $G$-modules, for all maps $\lambda: S\uparrow \to M_2$, if there's a map of $H$-modules $S\uparrow \to M_1$ making the diagram commute on restriction to $H$ then there's a map of $G$-modules making it commute.  This follows from the universal property of induction.

Now apply this to the surjeciton $U\downarrow \uparrow \to U$ and $S\uparrow \to U$, where the first map is the natural surjection and the second is projection onto the $U$ factor.  There is a $H$-map $S\uparrow \to U\downarrow \uparrow$ making this commute: project onto $U$, include this into $U\downarrow \uparrow$ by $u \mapsto 1\otimes u$.  Thus there is a $G$-map $S\uparrow \to U\downarrow\uparrow$ making everything commute.  This restricts to a $G$-map $U \to U\downarrow\uparrow$ splitting the natural surjection, so $U|U\downarrow\uparrow$.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry I had misunderstood your answer earlier.  This is quite clear to show the equivalence of U|U↓↑ and U|S↑.